# When to use Akka Microkernel?

Tags: java, scala, akka

I am reading the Akka docs and am curious about something that is really not explained all that well. They [mention](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/intro/deployment-scenarios.html) something called the *Akka Microkernel*, and allude that its some kind of app bootstrapper/launcher, but they don't really explain what it is and *when to use it*.

Later on in the docs there is an [entire page](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/java/microkernel.html) dedicated to the Microkernel, but its equally as mysterious and vague, stating:

> The Akka Microkernel is included in the Akka download found at downloads.

And then:

> To run an application with the microkernel you need to create a Bootable class that handles the startup and shutdown the application. An example is included below.

But nowhere in there is an explanation of what the microkernel is and why I would ever need to use it. Ideas?

Comment: Akka has to be one of the most frustrating technologies to adopt IMO. There is a dearth of good documentation out there. Still waiting for the "Akka in Action" book to be released.

Comment: Thanks @I.K. (+1) - but *trust* me, [GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/)'s got Akka beat in the *practical documentation/support* category by a mile, and then some.

Comment: Note that Akka Microkernel is now [deprecated](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.10/scala/microkernel.html), so the answer to the question now is probably "never"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Viktor Klang the inventor of the Microkernel:

> The primary use-case was to create a bundle so one can easily package an Akka Application and deploy/run it somewhere else (without having to write launcher scripts or installing some kind of App Server).

and

> It's a very lightweight packaging of an Akka application in a distributable archive.

[This](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/HJiZIex_6v8) Google post may shed more light on the matter for you.

Comment: Thanks again @I.K. (+1) - any incling as to why its called a *Microkernel* then?!? Sounds like a name that is almost intentionally convoluted. Based on what you're saying, it sounds like it's more of a "Deployer" or "Launcher". I also see the term *kernel* thrown around a lot in other parts of the Akka docs. Is this "kernel" terminology buzzword cross-pollination from Erlang perhaps?

Comment: Traditionally in computer science the term microkernel refers to the smallest piece of software that can provide all the needed functionality of an OS. I *guess* Viktor is leveraging that concept by naming this functionality as such because the use-case here is to drop the smallest Akka implementation possible in your application to make it Akka-enabled.